# c code generation for matlab function griddata

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

In one of my application I am using matlab griddata function. I want to generate c code the same. But it is not supported by the matlab coder. One possible solution is to rewrite the griddata function by removing cell arrays and variable number of arguments.. But there are some inbuilt functions like DelaunayTri and z=F(xi,yi) for which I am not able see the code.

Please let me know any other alternative way to generate c code.. or is there any alternate matlab code for griddata which supports c code generation..

Comment: Hi, you may know this,but I want to mention it just in case. The functions in which the code can not be seen, is not written in matlab. They are written in another language (eg c) and then compiled to a mex file. This may cause trouble when you are going to compile your own mex file using the already compiled `delaunay` function.

Comment: Yes you are correct.. But to write in C we should know the functionality atleast. I am even ready to write c code as my final target is to generate c code and port it on hardware. So if anyone knows alternate c code for griddata let me know..